# What is the best way to store and work with locale-dependent regular expressions in Android?

Tags: android, regex, localization

I use a bunch of locale-dependent Regular Expressions in my project,

For example (a simplest one):

```
\b(one|two|three|...|\d+)\b
```

So I want to store those regular expressions in something like `values-en/re.xml` and then use them through `Context`/`R.re.*` to parse the string that entered by user.

```
<string name="number_re">\b(one|two|three|...|\d+)\b</string>
```

So if he uses Russian locale and enters some phrase in Russian, I will use `values-ru/re.xml` with some value like:

```
<string name="number_re">\b(один|два|три|...|\d+)\b</string>
```

Is it the proper way intended (and it will not fail on some special characters used in both string resources and regular expressions) or there is another way to do it that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's considered proper or not proper (that's more of a app by app case). This seems like a reasonable approach. I mean you have separated out the locale specific aspect of your algorithm into place that has a mechanism for loading content by locale. Technically these regexes are resources. If it works for you and you aren't hindered by it now, I don't forsee this coming back and causing issues later.